# Facebook Login EventListener Not Working With Facebook Login Button

Tags: android, facebook, titanium-mobile, addeventlistener

I have added a Facebook login button to a view (have also tried adding it to a window). The button works in bringing up the Facebook login modal, but after successfully signing in, nothing happens... it does not change the state of the login button (to logout) or fire the "login" eventlistener.

Could someone please have a look at what I am doing wrong?

```
exports.login = function()
{
    Titanium.Facebook.appid = "XXXXXXXXX";
    Titanium.Facebook.permissions = ['publish_stream', 'read_stream','email'];

    Ti.App.viewLogin = Ti.UI.createView({
        top: Math.round((80 * Ti.Platform.displayCaps.dpi)/160),
        left:0,
        right:0,
        bottom: 0,
        backgroundImage:'../images/background.png',
        zIndex:99
    });

    // Main View
    var loginView = Titanium.UI.createScrollView({
        contentWidth: 'auto',
        contentHeight: 'auto',
        top:'0dp',
        layout:'vertical',
        showVerticalScrollIndicator: true
    });

    var fbLogin = Titanium.Facebook.createLoginButton({
        style:'wide',
        top:'85dp',
    });

    Ti.App.viewLogin.add(loginView);
    Ti.App.viewLogin.add(fbLogin);

    Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(Ti.App.viewLogin);

    Titanium.Facebook.addEventListener('logout', function(e){
        alert("Logout");
    });

    Ti.Facebook.addEventListener('login',function(e){
        if(Titanium.Facebook.loggedIn)
        {
            Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('me', {}, 'GET', function(e) {
                var userInfo = JSON.parse(e.result);
                alert(userInfo.id);
            });
        }   
    });
};
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message? or exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using just

```
    Ti.Facebook.authorize()
```

Rather than the facebook button?

**Edit**

Also try:

```
    Ti.Facebook.logout()
```

Before any auth happens - whether you're using the button or the .authorize() call.